# twisted Int16StringReceiver little endian byte order

Tags: python, python-2.7, byte, twisted

I'm trying to use [this class](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.1.0/api/twisted.protocols.basic.Int16StringReceiver.html) provided by twisted to frame my tcp stream. But the default format they have is in big endian byte order but I need to read in little endian.

So I did:

```
class Player(basic.Int16StringReceiver):
    structFormat = "<H"

    def stringReceived(self, packet):
        print ':'.join(x.encode('hex') for x in packet)
```

But for some reason `stringReceived` seldom gets called. Both client and server is on the same machine and I am very sure the client did send the data.

So why is `stringReceived` not being called every time data is received.

I tried overriding `dataReceived`:

```
class Player(basic.Int16StringReceiver):
    structFormat = "<H"

    def dataReceived(self, recd):
        print ':'.join(x.encode('hex') for x in recd)
```

And it does print out every time the client sends data. So why isn't `stringReceived` getting called? Maybe a miss-frame? But why?

Comment: May I see client protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client is supposed to send message like this:

```
len(string)string
```

where len(string) - should be packed according to format used by server.

Here is what happens in `IntNStringReceiver.sendString`

```
 self.transport.write(
     pack(self.structFormat, len(string)) + string)
```

Just to confirm, `Int16StringReceiver` is not integers sender/receiver. What it does is: send bytes messages over transport in the format mentioned above. And it is bad idea to override `dataReceived` the way you did it. This method is pretty complicated as you can see in the source code.

My advise: make sure client really sends `len(string)string`, where `len(string)` is packed using `<H` format.

I tested a client that use different from server format, and the server just goes crazy.

Comment: Aah, I see. so it requires `|` but I am actually using a binary protocol and not a string. I'm just leveraging the given library. Anyways, I'll just find another alternative. My protocol is `(len)(msg)`.

Comment: `|` is just visual seperator

Comment: well yes my format is len(string+self)string or example. `04 00 00 00`. That is my format. `< uint16 len > < msg >`. So the size includes itself.

Comment: Don't include size of size to length. Length thing should be equal to length of msg

Comment: yea, but I need to. So I guess I'll just implement my own framing then. Thanks though.